# jquery getting value of input text returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a input text that is created with jquery and now I am trying to get the value of the input text when a button is pressed, but its returning undefined:

here is what I am trying to do:

`$("#" + value).val(); \\value is 'ABC-123'`

and here is my input text that is created via jQuery:

```
 html += '<td><input type="text" name="' + key + '-' + taskArray[i] + '" id="' + key + '-' + taskArray[i] + '" class="vendorDropdown" value="' + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] + '" /></td>'; //key is ABC, taskArray[i] is 123 and value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] is the value, if its blank then in the input it will return just value
```

what am I doing wrong ? When I put text in the input text i expect that to be the value.

Here is a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/22dg6oyr/ but I cant get the jquery to run with it.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle?

Comment: Why can't you get jQuery to run with it? I selected jQuery from the Frameworks menu, it ran fine. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/22dg6oyr/1/

Comment: could it be that I am creating this input text inside an ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet would produce something like: (notice the hyphen between ABC and 123)

```
<td><input type="text" name="ABC-123" id="ABC-123" class="vendorDropdown" /></td>
```

Therefore, in your first snippet, `value` should be `ABC-123` instead.

Comment: that was a typo - in my first snippet of code, value is ABC-123 so they do match

Answer (score 0):

The text element that you created has a name of "ABC-123" (note the hyphen).  If value is "ABC123" (no hyphen) then it won't match any element.

Comment: in my first snippet of code, value is ABC-123 so they do match